# Spray request - Complete request only after nested futures

Tags: scala, akka, spray, spray-client

New to spray and scala. Been struggling to get it right for couple of days now. 
I am trying to merge facebook oauth2 login + user login details into the database in case the same user logs in by different ways(user/pass or fb login).

Pasting below spray routing snippet.

```
  path("facebook") {
    post{
      entity(as[JObject]) { json =>
        val fb: FacebookAuthModel = json.extract[FacebookAuthModel]
        complete {

          //Get user details from fb oauth2
          val fbUser = fbAuth.getIdentity(fb) match {
            case Right(user: User) => user
            case Left(error: Failure) => throw new FailureException(error)
          }

          //Check if user is already present either by fb id or email
          val userFuture = userRepo(FetchUserByFacebook(fbUser.facebook.get,fbUser.email))

          userFuture.map {
            case u: User => {

              //user present but fb id not attached yet
              if (u.facebook.isEmpty) {
                //update fb id for the user - fire to actor and forget, i.e no callback to sender
                userRepo(UpdateFacebookId(u.id.get, fbUser.facebook.get))
              }

              //complete request with a token - request(1)
              AuthToken(token=jwt.createToken(u))
            }
            case None => {

              //first time user using fb login
              userRepo(CreateUser(fbUser)).map {

                //complete request with the token - request(2)
                case createdUser: User => AuthToken(token=jwt.createToken(createdUser))

                case None => throw new FailureException(Failure("Not able to CreateUser", FailureType.Unauthorized))
              }
            }
          }
        }  
      }
    }
  }
```

Everything works fine except in case of first time user using fb login (refer request(2)).
Request gets completed with empty response before the nest future could complete.

I tried flatMapping the result from userFuture and then using onComplete on it to give the appropriate response, but it din't work.

Any idea how I could successfully complete the request(request(2)) with the token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one of the two branches in your code execution path could result in a `Future`, then you have to code to this as the lowest common denominator when dealing with `userFuture`.  That means `flatMap` on `userFuture` and using `Future.successful` in the case where you don't have an explicit second `Future` to deal with.  Something along this line:

```
def handleUserResult(a:Any):Future[AuthToken] = a match{
  case u:User =>              
    if (u.facebook.isEmpty) {                
      userRepo(UpdateFacebookId(u.id.get, fbUser.facebook.get))
    }              
    Future.successful(AuthToken(token=jwt.createToken(u)))

  case None =>              
    userRepo(CreateUser(fbUser)).map {
      case createdUser: User =>
        AuthToken(token=jwt.createToken(createdUser))

      case None => 
        throw new FailureException(Failure("Not able to CreateUser", FailureType.Unauthorized))
    }
}
```

Once you define that method, you can use it on `userResult` as follows:

```
userResult.flatMap(handleUserResult)
```

I didn't check this code for compilation issues.  I was more trying to show the general approach of `flatMap` used to handle two cases, one that produces another second `Future` and one that does not.

Comment: Thanks. That works. I did try flatMapping  Future[Future[User]] to Future[User] (and using Future.successful(user)) ,but made something stupid with that resultant future variable to throw some error when I tried before.